# pandas - find maximum of multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this simple multiindex dataframe `df` obtained after performing some `groupby.size()` operations:

```
U  G  C 
1  1  en    0.600000
   2  en    0.400000
2  1  es    0.333333
   3  es    0.500000
```

I would like to mask only the rows having the maximum value of the last column with respect to the `U` index column. So far I tried grouping by:

```
mask = df.groupby(level=[0]).max()
```

which returns:

```
U
1    0.6
2    0.5
```

but I would need the whole structure of the dataframe:

```
U  G  C 
1  1  en
2  3  es
```

How can I reset in some way the multiindex dataframe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your `df`:

```
            data
U G C           
1 1 en  0.600000
  2 en  0.400000
2 1 es  0.333333
  3 es  0.500000
```

You can use

```
df[df['data'] == df.groupby(level=[0])['data'].transform(max)]
```

which returns

```
        data
U G C       
1 1 en   0.6
2 3 es   0.5
```